# OSX: Android Emulator Crashes

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've just reinstalled  eclipse indigo (32bit) and the latest Android SDK. The Android Emulator crashes immediately after it is launched.

Here are my steps:

1. Create a new Adroid project. Target is Android 4.0, SDK 14.
2. Press the Run button in Eclipse.
3. See the Emulator launch and crash about 2 seconds later

Output of crash window:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

The Eclipse console complains about the following:

```
Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView,
which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
goldfish_fb_load: framebuffer dimensions mismatch
savevm: unable to load section goldfish_fb
emulator-5554 disconnected!
Cancelling 'com.sparky1.HelloAnrdroidActivity activity launch'!
```

Any thoughts about how to get emulator to behave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been reported as a Bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=724

There are some workarounds presented in this post, too. But at this point, there seams to be no actual fix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried the workarounds listed above ^. No luck. The emulator still crashes immediately every time I try to run it.

Comment: Reinstalling ultimately got me going again

Comment: The best workaround is not to workaround and use a real device. Sad but true.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this happens when an external monitor is connected. Try disconnecting your external monitor and then start emulator. You can attach it back after the emulator starts.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem too. I've found that running emulator from command line and disabling snapshots help a lot.
I'm running:

```
$ emulator -no-snapshot-load @avd
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. I'm afraid I'm having No luck here either. Actually adding this for me makes the emulator crash faster. With this, it crashes in a faction of a second.

Comment: Create a new avd. Set hw.lcd.density to 240. Use -scale 0.5 to let the window fit on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

If disable snapshot when create device, ok. Do not enable snapshot.
If enable snapshot, it's ok to check "save to snapshot" when launch device.
But check "launch from snapshot" is not ok. If already save snapshot, it will cause emulator-arm crash.
After emulator-arm crash by "launch from snapshot", disable snapshot with AVD manager does not work. But run config > target > additional command line option(-no-snapshot-load) works.

Answer (score 0):

I had all these crashes as well and found this in my crash logs:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x97585bc1 CFStringGetLength + 17
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9759df63 CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale + 35
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9759df2c CFStringCompare + 60
3   com.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.CamCamX5      0x03ff3b44 CoreBundleyes::IsMainMember() const + 48
4   com.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.CamCamX5      0x03ff11cc QVDigBaseClass::ClassFactory(ComponentInstanceRecord*) + 50
5   com.b-l-a-c-k-o-p.CamCamX5      0x03ff317b QVDIG_DATA_Open + 23
```

After spending only a couple of hours :-( on the net I found a tip to remove
 **/Library/Quicktime/CamCamX5.component**
After that no more crashes :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to switch to using AndroVM in Virtual Box which is an X86 Android image. The big advantage is that it is lightning fast compared to the ARM one. It boots in 2-3 secs. The downside is that you have to manually do the ADB connection and the capturing of the mouse by virtual box is a pain. Not all applications will run on the x86 as well.

To use it you have to configure the first Ethernet adapter as Host Only, run the androVM configuration utility to get the emulator's IP address, then use adb connect ip-address

Another tip is that if the screen times out you need to hit F1 to wake it up.